# How to change Angular Cli bundle path?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

After building my application in my index.html, the file reference looks like below,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.c15b1b72bcd63b7c92ca.bundle.js"></script>
```

(for example I have shown only for this file).

Since, I have to run my application in server **"xyzwebsite.com/app"**.

I need to copy bundled files to the **"app"** folder, but when I try to do that I get *404 not found* error.

I am new for Angular cli and bundling the app and all these stunts!  How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

ng build  **--base-href /app/**

At first I expected that changing the base tag in index.html would do the trick:
 
But after build it seems to be set to default (/) unless you add the above mentioned **option**.

Comment: Oh yes! First even i tried that and faced the same. But dint try it in this way though!

Answer (score 4):

**Using webpack.config.js**

If you want much more control to change bundle path using `webpack.config.js` file rather than `.angular-cli.json` file then do this.

```
1. Run `ng eject`
```

This command will expose `webpack.config.js` file in your root directory. You can configure that file.

```
2. Run `npm install`
```

As npm eject will add new dependencies related to loaders, those needs to be installed which can be done using above command.

```
3. "output": {
    "path": path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
    "filename": "scripts/[name].[chunkhash:20].bundle.js",
    "chunkFilename": "scripts/[id].[chunkhash:20].chunk.js"
  }
```

In `webpack.config.js` file edit output entry and add your desired directory name for JS files as shown above. Using this, you can get control over bundling path.

I hope this will be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli), you can just specify the `root` and the `outdir` parameter which will define the location for your file. Just set them to your /app directory and you'll be fine.

Having to move your generated file somewhere else does not seems to be a good idea in my opinion, better way is to directly generate them in the right location.